# I have two checkbox on my page, but the second always return false for my model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have two checkbox in my "View", the first working well, if checked, return true, if not checked, return false, but the second always return false.

They have the same implementation

```html
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcgsyITAAAAAHiF8A1MGysKGUfQddq-_uzBD8ba"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-8  checkbox-inline">
            <input asp-for="Aceite" />
            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Li e concordo com os termos de uso e privacidade</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-8  checkbox-inline">
            <input asp-for="AceitePromocao" />
            <label asp-for="AceitePromocao"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-pull-12">
            <input type="submit" value="Aceitar e concluir" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZrMa.png)

[controller get value false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxVRo.jpg)

```html
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("EstudanteCursoID,EstudanteID,InteresseID,MatriculaID,Aceite, AceitePromacao, DataAceite, Ip")] EstudanteCurso estudanteCurso)
        {
            var estudante = TempData.Get<Estudante>("Estudante");
            var matricula = TempData.Get<Matricula>("Matricula");
            var interesse = TempData.Get<Interesse>("Interesse");

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(estudante);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                estudanteCurso.EstudanteID = estudante.ID;
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (matricula != null)
                {
                    _context.Add(matricula);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    estudanteCurso.MatriculaID = matricula.ID;
                }
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (interesse != null)
                {
                    _context.Add(interesse);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    estudanteCurso.InteresseID = interesse.ID;
                }
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                estudanteCurso.IP = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
                estudanteCurso.DataAceite = DateTime.Now;
                _context.Add(estudanteCurso);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("WellCome", "EstudanteCursos", new { area = "" });
            }
            return View(estudanteCurso);
        }
```

```html
 public class EstudanteCurso
    {
        public int EstudanteCursoID { get; set; }
        public int? MatriculaID { get; set; }
        public int? InteresseID { get; set; }
        public int EstudanteID { get; set; }
        public bool Aceite { get; set; }
        [Display(Name ="Desejo receber informaçãoes sobre vagas de emprego e cursos")]
        public bool AceitePromocao { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataAceite { get; set; }
        public string IP { get; set; }

        public virtual Estudante Estudante { get; set; }
        public virtual Matricula Matricula { get; set; }
        public virtual Interesse Interesse { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add your server-side code, including the controller and the model?

Comment: Yes my model and my controller are ok

Comment: I am asking you to include that code in the question... just in case they are not okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
<input asp-for="AceitePromocao" />
```

in your markup, but

```
[Bind("EstudanteCursoID,EstudanteID,InteresseID,MatriculaID,Aceite, AceitePromacao, DataAceite, Ip")]
```

Different spelling: "AceitePromocao" vs "AceitePromacao"

Comment: Just another reason to use view models and never use `[Bind]` :)

Comment: Perfect, Thank's Chris and ok Stephen.